# Remove last character from variable

Tags: ansible

I am trying to remove the last character of the below output but I am having trouble doing it:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ ansible_mounts|json_query('[?mount == `/`].device') }}"
  register: rootpart
```

The below works with simple text:

```yaml
- debug:
  msg: "{{ '/dev/sda4'[:-1] }}"
```

But not with a variable:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ rootpart[:-1] }}"
```

Error:

> msg: Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{ rootpart[:-1] }}): unhashable type: 'slice'

Answer (score 3):

There is a big *"don't"* in your current attempt: you should not register on a `debug` task.
If you want to create a new variable, then use the [`set_fact`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/set_fact_module.html) module.

This is not only a better way to do it, it is also saving you from having a dictionary with the keys `changed`, `failed` and `msg` to dive into in order to get the variable you were expecting out of the `msg` property.

Then, your `json_query` is going to return you a list of devices, no matter if there is only one match thanks to your filter. So, you also need to get the first element of this list.

So, with all this, here are your two tasks:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    root_part: "{{ ansible_mounts | json_query(_query) }}"
  vars:
    _query: "[?mount == `/`].device | [0]"

- debug:
    var: root_part[:-1]
```